# JavaScript get available files in path

Tags: javascript, file, directory, path

Is there a way to get all of the available files in a certain path with javascript?

An example would be that the user would type a place of a folder into an **<input>** like **"C:\Program Files"** and JavaScript would get some array of all the available folders in their **Program Files** folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JS doesn't have access to the file system / hierarchy. Server side JS is a different story but I think you don't mean to ask about it.

Comment: Yes, nothing server side just the files of the person looking at the site. Then i will make the users define the path themselves.. Thank you